# How to square an array of numbers in ruby with while without `each` `map` or `collect` methods?

Tags: arrays, ruby, methods, square

I'm new to coding in RUBY. I'm trying to write a method that squares each element in an array of numbers and returns a new array of these numbers squared. Trying to use while loop and NOT use `each`, `collect`, or `map`. Having trouble understanding how to index/loop each individual element of array and square is (**).

This is what makes sense to me but I know its wrong.

```
def square_array(numbers)
  count = 0
  while count < numbers.length do
    numbers.index ** 2 
  end
  square_array(numbers)
end
```

Will anyone please help me? Thanks!

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain, what *precisely* is unclear to you about [the documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#class-Array-label-Accessing+Elements). That way, the Ruby developers can improve the documentation so that future developers don't stumble over the same problems. Help make the world a better place!

Comment: @JörgWMittag Good luck with that. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy way to do it is `map`, of course:

```
def square_array(numbers)
    numbers.map { |e| e ** 2 }
end
```

But here's what you have to do to do the same with a `while` loop (which is good practice).

1. Create an array to contain the transformed data.
2. Create a counter (you've done that).
3. Set up your `while` loop (as you have it, except you don't need the `do` at the end).
4. Write a statement that squares the array element whose index is the same as your counter, and pushes that result into the array you created in step 1.
5. Increment your counter by 1 (you forgot to do that, so you'll be getting an endless loop since `count` will always equal zero).
6. Return the array you created in step 1.

That will do it for you! See if you can put that together, rather than me just giving you the code.

Answer (score 2):

```
def square_array(numbers)
  # Allocate an array with the same size as `numbers`
  # so that the runtime does not have to resize it from time to time
  result = Array.new(numbers.size)

  # The index
  i = 0

  while i < numbers.size
    # Fill the result array
    result[i] = numbers[i] ** 2

    # and don't forget to increase the index,
    # otherwise the loop will run forever.
    i += 1
  end

  # Return the result array
  result
end
```

Comment: I’d better go with `while numbers.shift` later. That approach would work on infinite input enumerators, unlike `size`. This mutates the argument, though..

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin I think keeping the argument `numbers` unchanged is the whole point of returning a new array, so I will not use `shift`. Besides, if `numbers` is an infinite enumerator, then `square_array` will never return, maybe it's better to `yield` something in this case.

Comment: Yeah, agreed. `numbers.dup` in the first line would help to avoid mutating, but it’d break the lazy enumeration, so I honestly dunno.

Comment: It looks like FORTRAN but I think it's the closest to what OP wanted.

Comment: Does the size allocation up front outperform pushing values one by one onto an initially empty array?

Comment: @BobRodes According to my benchmark (square 10 million integers), it's about 18% faster with pre-allocation than without it (0.641s vs 0.781s). Besides, `Array#map` is about 9% faster (0.720s) than the naive while loop (without pre-allocation). BTW, `Array#map` also preallocates the target array under the hood.

Comment: @Aetherus Thanks very much, that's very interesting. Especially the part about `Array#map` pre-allocating the target array under the hood. I thought that might be the reason that you did the pre-allocation, but wasn't sure.

Answer (score 2):

The more functional approach would be to use recursion.

```
fun =
  ->(acc = [], arr, map, fun) {
    arr.empty? ? acc : fun.(acc << map.(arr.shift), arr, map, fun)
  }
#⇒ #<Proc:0x000055ab64333fa0@(pry):12 (lambda)>
```

And for any mapper (e. g. square root,) use it like:

```
fun.([1,2,3,4,5], ->(e) { e ** 2 }, fun)
#⇒ [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
```

Please note! This approach *mutates* the initial array, so it should be explicitly `array.dup`’ed  before passing to the function. To eliminate the necessity to pass the function itself through *and* leave the initial array intact, we would need a wrapper.

```
fun =
  ->(acc = [], arr, map, fun) {
    arr.empty? ? acc : fun.(acc << map.(arr.shift), arr, map, fun)
  }
#⇒ #<Proc:0x000055ab64333fa0@(pry):12 (lambda)>
mapper = ->(arr, map) { fun.([], arr.dup, map, fun) }
```

And use it like:

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
mapper.(arr, ->(e) { e ** 2 })
#⇒ [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
arr
#⇒ [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: If it mutates the original array, how is it "more functional"? Side-effects are pretty much the *opposite* of functional!

Comment: @JörgWMittag By wrapping this function in `->(arr, map) { fun.([], arr.dup, map, fun)}` I could have eliminated _both_ the necessity to pass `fun` as a name through _and_ the side effect and I clearly stated it in the post scriptum. I decided not to do this to make the code shorter. OK, I will do.

Comment: This is very interesting stuff, although I can't imagine the OP having a clue what you're up to! I'm sure it will be useful to someone else, though.

Answer (score 1):

```
def sq(arr)
  enum = arr.each
  a = []
  loop do
    n = enum.next
    a << n*n
  end
  a
end
```

```
sq [1, 2, 3, 4]
  #=> [1, 4, 9, 16]
```

See [Array#each](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-each), [Kernel#loop](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Kernel.html#method-i-loop) and [Enumerator#next](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerator.html). One could use [Kernel#to_enum](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Object.html#method-i-to_enum) (documented in [Object](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Object.html)) in place of `Array#each`.

Comment: Interesting approach, using an external iterator and `loop` so as not to have to increment and keep track of a counter.

Answer (score 0):

Using a for loop?

```
ary = [1,2,3]

res = []
for n in ary do
  res << n ** 2
end

res
#=> [1, 4, 9]
```

But better you stick with `map`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
def square_array(numbers)
  new_array = []
  counter = 0 
  while counter < numbers.length()
  new_array.push(numbers[counter] * numbers[counter])
  counter += 1
  end 
  return new_array
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using each, map, or collect.

```rb
def square_array(array)
 new_array = []
  array.length.times do |index|
  new_array.push(array[index] ** 2)
  end
 new_array
end
```